# Multiply two 100-Digit Numbers inside Excel Using Matrix

Tags: excel, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

I want to multiply two 100-Digit Numbers In Excel using matrix. The issue in Excel is that after 15-digit, it shows only 0. So, the output also need to be in a Matrix.

1st Number: "9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"

2nd Number: "2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222"

Output: "22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222217777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777778"

Comment: Have a look at this article? http://www.excel-ticker.com/calculation-of-very-large-numbers-in-excel-part-3-multiplication/

Comment: Hi, i have seen this article already. this gives the output inside a text feild, i am looking for something, which will divide the numbers in a 2D matrix and after that will the output also in a 2D Matrix

Comment: Sorry, I'm not with you. Can you explain a bit more or show the layout of the 2d array - how many rows and columns?

Comment: okay suppose i have a 2 numbers: 
1st: 2222 
2nd: 9999.

So, First Array will be: 
2  2
2  2

and Second Array Will Be:
9  9
9  9

Now there is way, in which i can multiply these 2 Arrays and there will be 3rd Array

X  X  X  X
X  X  X  X
X  X  X  X
X  X  X  X

Sum of the 3rd array will the result of 2222 * 9999.

I need the same thing for a 100-Digit Number

Comment: Yes exactly like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be what OP was after. I thought I would try a naive multiplication method to see how long it would take to run. The answer is less than a second for two 100-digit numbers. You have to select the output range (i.e. A3:GR3 for a 200-digit result) and enter the formula containing the input ranges as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> e.g.

```
=Multiply(A1:CV1,A2:CV2)
```

for two 100-digit numbers.

The method is basically just a simulation of school maths long multiplication, except that the intermediate rows are not stored but immediately added to the answer thus saving a lot of space.

The utility of it is obviously not that it is a replacement for the Karatsuba method, but it is a simple verifiable method which could be used for one-off calculations.

Currently limited to multiplication of rows containing more than one cell (so if you wanted to multiply by a single digit number, would have to enter it as e.g. 09).

Start of numbers

[image: ![enter image description here]

Middle of numbers

[image: ![enter image description here]

End of numbers

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
Function Multiply(rng1 As Variant, rng2 As Variant)

Dim arr() As Integer
Dim arrLength, r1Length, r2Length, carry, product, digit As Integer
Dim tot, totDigit, totCarry As Integer
Dim v1, v2 As Variant

v1 = rng1
v2 = rng2
r1Length = UBound(v1, 2)
r2Length = UBound(v2, 2)

arrLength = r1Length + r2Length

' Declare 1D array with enough space

ReDim arr(1 To arrLength)

' Loop over digits in first number starting from right

For i = r1Length To 1 Step -1
carry = 0
totCarry = 0

' Loop over digits in second number starting from right

    For j = r2Length To 1 Step -1

' Calculate next digit in intermediate values (i.e. one row of long multiplication)

    product = v1(1, i) * v2(1, j) + carry
    digit = product Mod 10
    carry = Int(product / 10)

' Calculate next digit in final values (i.e. totals line of long multiplication)

    tot = arr(i + j) + digit + totCarry
    arr(i + j) = tot Mod 10
    totCarry = Int(tot / 10)

    Next j

' Process final carry

arr(i) = carry + totCarry
Next i

' Return as an array

Multiply = arr

End Function
```

Comment: That's great. I will alter it so it doesn't put a leading zero in.

Answer (score 0):

OK it might work like this:-

(1) You need to concatenate your numbers into a string because that's what you need as the input to your function. Native Excel won't do concatenation on arrays so you need a UDF like [this one](http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/05/28/how-to-add-a-range-of-cells-in-excel-concat/). So B2 contains

```
=concat(D1:G1)
```

(2) The output from the function is a string so you need to split it back into separate cells. You could use another UDF or a formula like this one copied across:-

```
=IF(COLUMNS($C3:C3)>LEN($B$3),"",VALUE(MID($B3,COLUMNS($C3:C3),1)))
```

So for the simple example it would look like this:-

[image]

But I might have got the wrong end of the stick completely.

Comment: Good question. This would indeed contain the call to the Karatsuba function but I must admit I haven't tested it! I'm assuming the question is more about getting the input & results in the right form.

Comment: i have tried the karatsuba function, but it is good for only upto 10 digits, I need a function that can handle 100 digits.

Comment: I thought the whole point of the Karatsuba function was that it could handle a virtually unlimited number of digits? I started to try and test it yesterday, but ran out of time - will let you know if I get anywhere.

Comment: BTW the Karatsuba function would just use normal multiplication and immediately return on the small examples above. I suppose if all else fails the alternative would be to use naïve long multiplication but it would be slow. Worth asking how many times this calculation would be repeated?

Answer (score 0):

Place your arrays into A1:A100 and B1:B100, then use three formulas:

1) In `C2:C200` enter this as an array formula:

```
=MMULT(IFERROR(INDEX(A1:A100*TRANSPOSE(B1:B100),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(A1:A100)*2-1))>0)+TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(A1:A100))))-1,MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(A1:A100)*2-1))-TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(A1:A100)))),ROWS(A1:A100)*2-1)+1),0),SIGN(A1:A100+1))
```

2) In `D1` enter `=C1+INT(D2/10)` and fill down to `D200`.

3) In `E1` enter `=MOD(D1,10)` and fill down to `D200`.

`E1:E200` will contain the answer.