# Auto Generate Number Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

how to generate auto number from 0,000000000000000000000000000001 till 0,999999999999999999999999999999 at excel and the format cell is number ?

i've tried for dragging mouse , but i guess thats so terrible

Comment: You'd have to use the sort of approach that I tried here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943905/multiply-two-100-digit-numbers-inside-excel-using-matrix/33016197#33016197 but as @Bathsheba says there would be far too many cells to fit in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Actually it would also exceed the total storage available on the planet, which was something of the order of 10^20 bytes a few years ago http://www.computerworld.com/article/2513110/data-center/scientists-calculate-total-data-stored-to-date--295--exabytes.html

Answer (score 1):

You're out of luck.

Excel uses a 64 bit double precision IEEE754 floating point type for numbers (along with some clever rounding tricks). That gives you 53 bits of precision which loosely translates to 15 decimal significant figures of accuracy.

You will not be able to descriminate between numbers with such a small interval between them, if the total range is between 0 and 1.

(There's also the small matter of there not being enough space in a workbook to represent all those numbers.)

Comment: Even if you could get the accuracy, you'd need 10^30 cells. The computer wouldn't have nearly enough memory for that.