# Excel 2013 - accuracy support for big numbers?

Tags: excel, office365, floating-accuracy

I'm using Excel 2013 and in one cell I have :

`=26*25*24*23*22*21*20*19*18*17*16*15*14*13*12*11*10*9*8*7`

The right [result](http://web2.0calc.com/) is : `560127029342507827200000`

But Excel shows : `560,127,029,342,508,000,000,000`

The settings are :

[image]

**Question:**

How can I make excel show the right result ?

Nb - precision as displayed is OFF :

[image]

Comment: You could have a look at this if you are interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943905/multiply-two-100-digit-numbers-inside-excel-using-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel has a maximum of 15 digits of precision for numbers.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=Excel_2016-2013

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Excel only supports approximately 15 digits of precision (floating point doubles).