# Use 64 bit integers in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, long-integer

Is there a way to force excel to use the integer format instead of double ?
For example:

```
A1: 122124841883276000
A2: 122124842368497000
A3:          485220992  =A2-A1   should be 485221000
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe you can do it natively. I did write a function a while ago to multiply two 100-digit numbers...who knows, I might as well do addition and subtraction because they would be easier, possibly attempt division some time in the future but I wouldn't like to put a timescale on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943905/multiply-two-100-digit-numbers-inside-excel-using-matrix?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: No, you cannot.  Excel is limited to 15 digit precision, and longer numbers will be stored in accord with the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754).  Using VBA, you can write routines which can be used within Excel to accurately handle calculations involving more precision. [xNumbers 6.0](http://www.thetropicalevents.com/Xnumbers60.htm) is one such routine.

Comment: @TomSharpe Maybe you could start with [xNumbers](http://www.thetropicalevents.com/Xnumbers60.htm).  I think its open source now but I don't know of anyone working on it. There probably remain some bugs, and the toolbar doesn't show up in Excel 2016, but there are many functions that work.  I don't have the knowledge to really do much with it.

Comment: It might save re-inventing the wheel :-)

Comment: What kind of operations do you need to do? There are work-arounds for simple ones.

Comment: I have a good amount of cvs logs containing different timestamps in different formats. I could parse the numbers and define a fixed and common amount of time to remove from the timestamps. The problem is that they are not all from the same reference in time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Lord.. Just it.. just implement our school math by converting each digit to individual string. then manually to 1 digit subtraction.

```
B5        =IF(C4<0,B2-1,"")
```

and drag to C5

```
C1       =MID($A1,COLUMN(C1)-2,1)   
C2       =MID($A2,COLUMN(C2)-2,1)   
A3       =A2-A1         
C4       =C2-C1 
C6       =IF(C4<0,10+IF(C5="",C2,C5)-C1,C4)
```

select C1:C6 and drag it until T6

finally :

```
A3       =VALUE(CONCATENATE(C6,D6,E6,F6,G6,H6,I6,J6,K6,L6,M6,N6,O6,P6,Q6,R6,S6,T6))
```

Hope that solves.. (: