# How to multiply long numbers in excel?

Tags: excel

How to multiply 1929868153955269923726183083478131797547292737984581739710086052358636024904 by 60
and the answer is whole number?
I want to try this in excel but everytime I copy pastE that long number, It shows rounding number, I want to paste it exactly and get the exact result not the 1.5792E+77

Comment: change format to `number`

Comment: I already did that, but same to get 000000 not the exact number

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943905/multiply-two-100-digit-numbers-inside-excel-using-matrix) might help

Comment: Thanks, but the method is complicated for me. Is there any simple way?

Comment: Multiply() or mmult() ? How did your tests go?

Comment: [xNumbers add-in](https://www.thetropicalevents.com/Xnumbers60.htm)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943905/multiply-two-100-digit-numbers-inside-excel-using-matrix/33016197#33016197

Comment: Note that this takes input and output as arrays one digit per cell, but the output range will now spill in Excel 365 making it a bit easier to use. I will produce a version that has input and output as strings.

Answer (score 1):

I've added a function which allows the two numbers to be multiplied to be passed as strings to the original Multiply function:

```
Option Base 1
Option Explicit

Function MultiplyString(s1 As String, s2 As String) As String

    Dim arr1() As Variant, arr2() As Variant, arr3 As Variant
    Dim length1 As Integer, length2 As Integer, i As Integer, length3 As Integer
    
    length1 = Len(s1)
    length2 = Len(s2)
    
    ReDim arr1(1 To length1)
    ReDim arr2(1 To length2)
    
    For i = 1 To length1
        arr1(i) = CInt(Mid(s1, i, 1))
    Next i
    
    For i = 1 To length2
        arr2(i) = CInt(Mid(s2, i, 1))
    Next i
           
    arr3 = Multiply(arr1, arr2)
    
    length3 = UBound(arr3, 1)
    
    MultiplyString = ""
    
    For i = 1 To length3
        MultiplyString = MultiplyString & CStr(arr3(i))
    Next i
    
    If Left(MultiplyString, 1) = "0" Then
        MultiplyString = Right(MultiplyString, Len(MultiplyString) - 1)
    End If


End Function




Function Multiply(v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant)

Dim arr() As Integer
Dim arrLength, v1Length, v2Length, carry, product, digit As Integer
Dim tot, totDigit, totCarry, i, j As Integer
'Dim v1, v2 As Variant

'v1 = rng1
'v2 = rng2
v1Length = UBound(v1, 1)
v2Length = UBound(v2, 1)

arrLength = v1Length + v2Length

' Declare 1D array with enough space

ReDim arr(1 To arrLength)

' Loop over digits in first number starting from right

For i = v1Length To 1 Step -1
carry = 0
totCarry = 0

' Loop over digits in second number starting from right

    For j = v2Length To 1 Step -1

' Calculate next digit in intermediate values (i.e. one row of long multiplication)

    product = v1(i) * v2(j) + carry
    digit = product Mod 10
    carry = Int(product / 10)

' Calculate next digit in final values (i.e. totals line of long multiplication)

    tot = arr(i + j) + digit + totCarry
    arr(i + j) = tot Mod 10
    totCarry = Int(tot / 10)

    Next j

' Process final carry

arr(i) = carry + totCarry
Next i

' Return as an array

Multiply = arr

End Function
```

[image]